# Arrange function: Conflict between lubridate and dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I want to rearrange a df with the function `arrange` from `dplyr`. The problem is that seems that these two packages have a conflict when I have another column (let's say v2) distinct from the column I want to arrange the df:

```
   library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

start_dates <- as.Date(1:10, origin = "2018-01-01")
my_df <- data.frame(x = 10:1, y = interval(start_dates, start_dates + 1), 
                    z=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))

my_df %>% arrange(z)
```

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
>         Column `y` classes Period and Interval from lubridate are currently not supported.

How I can order my dataframe? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It's difficult to help without know what your data look like. Use `dput()` to select a sample of your data and include it in your question.

Comment: I've edited the post so you have an example :)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call this a "conflict" per se, just one package not supporting the features of another.

If `dplyr`'s `arrange()` doesn't support `Interval` classes, just use `order()` like normal:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

start_dates <- as.Date(1:10, origin = "2018-01-01")
my_df <- data.frame(x = 10:1, y = interval(start_dates, start_dates + 1))

my_df %>% arrange(y)
```

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :
>     Column `y` classes Period and Interval from lubridate are currently not supported.

```
my_df[order(my_df$y), ]

#     x                              y
# 1  10 2018-01-02 UTC--2018-01-03 UTC
# 2   9 2018-01-03 UTC--2018-01-04 UTC
# 3   8 2018-01-04 UTC--2018-01-05 UTC
# 4   7 2018-01-05 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
# 5   6 2018-01-06 UTC--2018-01-07 UTC
# 6   5 2018-01-07 UTC--2018-01-08 UTC
# 7   4 2018-01-08 UTC--2018-01-09 UTC
# 8   3 2018-01-09 UTC--2018-01-10 UTC
# 9   2 2018-01-10 UTC--2018-01-11 UTC
# 10  1 2018-01-11 UTC--2018-01-12 UTC
```

#### Note

For future reference, I would take seriously the admonition by [OTStats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9855745/otstats) -- often without example data it is very difficult for others to help you. I would check out [How to Make a Great R Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've edited the original post with your example in order to clarify. I have one more question: Does ´order()´ accept more than one variable?

Comment: @ArmandoGonzálezDíaz Sure, you could do something like `foo[order(foo$bar, foo$baz), ]`. Check out `help("order")` for more details -- it's first argument is `...`, which accepts an arbitrary sequence of variables to order by

Comment: I've checked but it not works in the same way that arrange. Don't rename the columns

Comment: order shows the df in the right order, but when i made operations based in order i.e. `my_df$rank<-dplyr::ntile(my_df$z,30)` the operation is has not the same result when is ordered witharrange. furthermore, colnames is not replaced in order to be consecuent with new order